# Detecting Road from satellite image in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to detect roads from a satellite image! It can be any type of paved/asphalt road. I'm using OpenCV! The way I am trying is, first I used Canny to detect the edges, the I am trying to apply hough transform to detect the straight lines from the edges. Then I planned to detect circles to detect the curves of the roads. The problem I'm facing is, after doing canny, hough is not working. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //read an image
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("img2.jpg");
    //create image window named "My Image"
    cv::namedWindow("My Image");
    //show the image on the window
    cv::imshow("My Image", image);

    cv::Mat contours,hough;

    //canny
    cv::Canny(image, contours, 0, 100);
    cv::namedWindow("My Image2");
    cv::imshow("My Image2", contours);

    // Hough tranform for line detection
    std::vector<cv::Vec2f> lines;
    cv::HoughLines(contours, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 80, 0, 0);

    std::vector<cv::Vec2f>::const_iterator it= lines.begin();   
    while(it!=lines.end()) 
    {      
        float rho= (*it)[0];   
        // first element is distance rho      
        float theta= (*it)[1]; 
        //second element is angle theta            
        if(theta < CV_PI/4. || theta > 3.*CV_PI/4.) 
        { // ~vertical line               
            // point of intersection of the line with first row         
            cv::Point pt1(rho/cos(theta),0);                 
            // point of intersection of the line with last row         
            cv::Point pt2((rho-result.rows*sin(theta))/cos(theta),result.rows);         
            // draw a white line         
            cv::line( image, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(255), 1);       
        }
        else 
        { // ~horizontal line         
            // point of intersection of the          
            // line with first column         
            cv::Point pt1(0,rho/sin(theta));                 
            // point of intersection of the line with last column         
            cv::Point pt2(result.cols,(rho-result.cols*cos(theta))/sin(theta));         
            // draw a white line         
            cv::line(image, pt1, pt2, cv::Scalar(255), 1);       
        }      
        ++it;   
    }
    //show lines
    cv::namedWindow("My Image3");
    cv::imshow("My Image3", hough);
    //wait key for 5000ms
    cv::waitKey(80000);

    return 0;
}
```

In this code, I'm getting an error under "result" at line `cv::Point pt2((rho-result.rows*sin(theta))/cos(theta),result.rows);`

And another error under "result" at line `cv::Point pt2(result.cols,(rho-result.cols*cos(theta))/sin(theta));`

I can't figure it out what errors are those and what are the solutions! Any help would be appreciated :)
Also I'm totally new at computer vision, if you have any other easier and simpler way to accomplish my goal please feel free to share it :)

For your help I'm giving the sample image and the image of errors:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4qYRvG5emZDWXhNV2V2djZWdUk

Error is for the errors, Canny is after performing canny algorithm and input is the sample image I took!

NOTE: I'm following OpenCV cookbook for my codes!

Comment: what is result? where do you define it?
I'm sure you'll find an error message somewhere...

Comment: @Piglet please check this image. These are the error messages!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4qYRvG5emZDWDdUYy1tMGo3MDA